# Choosing Icon when several overlap in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, icons, mapping, openlayers, selection

In Openlayers I have 3 IconFeatures as dots displayed on a map that are right on top of each other. Is there a built in feature of Openlayres where I can get a list of the Icons near where I clicked? Maybe even a list of the underlying Icon objects?  Or do I have to implement my own quad tree or related structure?

Apologies if there is a simple solution. I am just getting started with Openlayers and I have not run through all the examples yet. Typical get this done last week task.

I saw the Icon Symbolizer example but when I copied the code and ran it myself the map was rendered but no icon was displayed unlikethe live example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html . I even found the missing data/icon.png file and

Comment: Check this example, it may be something that you can use or guide you to a solution [OL Example Earthquake Clusters](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html).

Comment: look for map.forEachFeatureAtPixel in a click event

Answer (score 0):

Use a Select interaction with the `multi` option set to true to get all (overlapping) features.
Listen to the `select` event and you will get an array of features.

```
    var select = new Select({
      multi: true
    });
    map.addInteraction(select);
    select.on('select', function(e) {
      console.log (
          e.target.getFeatures().getLength() +
          ' selected features (last operation selected ' + e.selected.length +
          ' and deselected ' + e.deselected.length + ' features)'
      );
    });
```